# How to declare a function that takes three different generic types and returns the sum of the squares of the two larger numbers?

Tags: rust

A naive approach is to assume all the numbers are of the same type:

```rust
fn e3(n1: f32, n2: f32, n3: f32) -> f32 {
    match (n1 <= n2, n1 <= n3, n2 <= n1, n2 <= n3) {
        (true, true, _, _) => n2 * n2 + n3 * n3,
        (_, _, true, true) => n1 * n1 + n3 * n3,
        _ => n1 * n1 + n2 * n2,
    }
}
```

However this won't work with number of multiple types (i.e. `i32`, `f32` or `u8`).

To implement a generic function I added these type constraints:

```rust
fn g_e3<T, U, V, R>(n1: T, n2: U, n3: V) -> R
where
    T: std::cmp::PartialOrd + std::ops::Mul + std::convert::From<U> + std::convert::From<V>,
    U: std::cmp::PartialOrd + std::ops::Mul + std::convert::From<T> + std::convert::From<V>,
    V: std::cmp::PartialOrd + std::ops::Mul + std::convert::From<T> + std::convert::From<U>,
    <T as std::ops::Mul>::Output: std::ops::Add,
    <U as std::ops::Mul>::Output: std::ops::Add,
{
    match (
        n1 <= n2.into(),
        n1 <= n3.into(),
        n2 <= n1.into(),
        n2 <= n3.into(),
    ) {
        (true, true, _, _) => n2 * n2 + n3 * n3,
        (_, _, true, true) => n1 * n1 + n3 * n3,
        _ => n1 * n1 + n2 * n2,
    }
}
```

However, to describe the result type `R` I need to add `R: <<U as std::ops::Mul>::Output as std::ops::Add>::Output` which is not allowed.

To circumvent the type rigidity I tried defining a macro:

```rust
macro_rules! ge3 {
    ($n1:expr, $n2:expr, $n3:expr) => {
        {
            match ($n1 <= $n2.into(), $n1 <= $n3.into(), $n2 <= $n1.into(), $n2 <= $n3.into()) {
                (true, true, _, _) => $n2 * $n2 + ($n3 * $n3).into(),
                (_, _, true, true) => $n1 * $n1 + ($n3 * $n3).into(),
                _ => $n1 * $n1 + ($n2 * $n2).into(),
            }
        }
    };
}
```

However, Rust has the notion of trivial (`as`) and non-trivial cast (`into`). Primitive casts won't work with `into`, you need to use `as`. However I cannot find a way to find the `type` of a particular `expr` within a macro.

Comment: Why did you choose to have **3** generic types, instead of just one? Do you really want to be able to pass in (as a hypothetical example) `g_e3(true, vec![1], 42.42)`?

Comment: It's actually an SICP problem on chapter one. The `number` type is not specified. So it could be `i32`, `f32`, `u8` etc respectively.

Answer (score 3):

You want to be too implicit about your types. You should let the user specify the return type. That does not only simplify your constraints, but it will save a lot of other headaches.

The main problem for your interface that you're facing is that the `Into` trait is not commutative. You can cast `u8` into `u32` but not vice-versa. It's better to pre-define a common target type, cast all integers to that first and then continue calculating with that type. Even more, your user may choose a bigger type because the squared sum may overflow with even the biggest provided input type.

That way your function could look as follows:

```
fn squared_sum<Res, N1, N2, N3>(n1: N1, n2: N2, n3: N3) -> Res
where
    N1: std::convert::Into<Res>,
    N2: std::convert::Into<Res>,
    N3: std::convert::Into<Res>,
    Res: std::cmp::PartialOrd + std::ops::Mul<Output = Res> + std::ops::Add<Output = Res> + Copy,
{
    let n1: Res = n1.into();
    let n2: Res = n2.into();
    let n3: Res = n3.into();
    match (n1 <= n2, n1 <= n3, n2 <= n1, n2 <= n3) {
        (true, true, _, _) => n2 * n2 + n3 * n3,
        (_, _, true, true) => n1 * n1 + n3 * n3,
        _ => n1 * n1 + n2 * n2,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let result: i32 = squared_sum(8_u8, 10_u16, 10_i32);
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

Note that you could ditch `N1`, `N2`, `N3` altogether and make the arguments `n1: impl Into<Res>`.